# How to create a "token" from a custom field

Tags: tokens

I'm trying to create a token from a custom fields, is there a way to do this?

My specific use case is that I want to have a custom field under Events that includes the Zoom event information (URL and call-in numbers), which I can then insert into email notifications regarding the event.

Answer (score 5):

This happens automatically - but you can't use an event token unless you're sending an email that is tied directly to the event.  E.g. you can't use CiviMail, because CiviMail doesn't know which event you're referencing.  However, Scheduled Reminders and CiviRules can use event tokens.

Because they're not available in CiviMail, they don't appear in the *Tokens* drop-down menu normally.  However, they appear if you create a Scheduled Reminder.  The format of the token is `{event.custom_X}` where `X` is the custom field ID.

If you go to **Administer menu » Communications » Schedule Reminders**, the *Tokens* menu will have your custom fields listed.  You can freely copy the token into other templates that you intend to use with Scheduled Reminders, CiviRules, as well as the "PDF Letters for Participants" action, and possibly some other Participant actions (e.g. Name Badges).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Jon Gs answer you may want to utilize this extension to send out manual or automated emails containing event & participant token using this extension: https://docs.civicrm.org/eventmessages/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to Jon's comments - if you send an email from the actions on the Find Participants screens event custom field tokens should be availble in the token selector (if you CiviCRM version is fairly recent)

Answer (score 0):

for a general user case, it's easy to create any token using the data processor extension and its addon the data processor token extension.